# Error ICE18: KeyPath for Component: 'DeviceStartup' is Directory:

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3

I am getting the below error when building my WIX project.

> ICE18: KeyPath for Component: 'DeviceStartup' is Directory: 'INSTALLDIR'.
> The Directory/Component pair must be listed in the CreateFolders
> table.    PCE1.0.1    E:\Data\PCE1\PCE1.0.1   E:\Data\PCE1\PCE1.0.1\PCE_WiX_Installer_EN.wxs  48  1   Build

Below is the code snippet:

```
<Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" ShortName="PCE" Name="PowerChart Application">
<Component Id="DeviceStartup" Guid="{52B316C2-77EA-11E0-B16E-49D64824019B}">
   <Shortcut Id="startupEXE" Directory="StartupFolder" Name="Device Status" ShortName="DeviceStat" Target="[INSTALLDIR]Display.exe" />
 </Component>
```

Where the error is showing at "Component" element.

For this as part of the workaround i have added KeyPath="yes" for "Component" element. With that i have resolved the issue.

Can i go with that workaround. please suggest?

Comment: Are you installing the file you make the shortcut to with this WiX package? Or is this a shortcut to a file that is already on disk?

Comment: I am installing this file with the WIX package.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

Could you just put the shortcut in the same component as the executable? There is a sample below. Do you install per-user or per-machine?

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">

  <Directory Id="StartupFolder" />

  <Component Id="Product.exe" Feature="Main">
     <File Source="Product.exe" KeyPath="yes">
        <Shortcut Id="startupEXE" Directory="StartupFolder" Name="Product" Advertise="yes" />
     </File>
  </Component>

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do stuff without creating any directory [the error can be silent](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/ICE18-Error-KeyPath-for-Component-td691204.html) using

```
<Component Id="DeviceStartup" Guid="{52B316C2-77EA-11E0-B16E-49D64824019B}">
        <CreateFolder/>
        <Shortcut Id="startupEXE" Directory="StartupFolder" Name="Device Status" ShortName="DeviceStat" Target="[INSTALLDIR]Display.exe" />
</Component>
```